# Write to last Node using linq to xml

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am using Linq to xml for creating a xml file. My xml format is like below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnJln.jpg)

`<weather>` element will be created in every time I iterate through loop. And every time I want to write something into latest `<weather>` element created. How do I do that?

Comment: please show your existing code.

Comment: foreach(XElement element in xdoc.Elements("Language").Elements("Text"))
            {
xTSDoc.Element("data").Add(new XElement("weather"));
  xTSDoc.Element("data").Element("weather").Add(new XElement("Text", element.Attribute("Number").Value));
                xTSDoc.Element("data").Element("weather").Add(new XElement("Name", element.Attribute("Name").Value));
}

Comment: I am not getting how to access the lastly added weather element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
foreach (XElement element in xdoc.Elements("Language").Elements("Text"))
{
    // method 1, store a reference..
    var weather = new XElement("weather");
    xTSDoc.Element("data").Add(weather);
    weather.Add(new XElement("Text", element.Attribute("Number").Value));
    weather.Add(new XElement("Name", element.Attribute("Name").Value));

    // method 2, get last element
    xTSDoc.Element("data").Add(new XElement("weather"));
    xTSDoc.Element("data").Elements("weather").Last().Add(new XElement("Text", element.Attribute("Number").Value));
    xTSDoc.Element("data").Elements("weather").Last().Add(new XElement("Name", element.Attribute("Name").Value));
}
```